# How to use jquery validate plugin inside a jquery UI dialog and in an asp form, all this in the same asp.net page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to use [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate both the controls inside a [jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and the controls inside an asp.net form.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var table = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button, input:submit, input:button").button();
        $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();

        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
        $("#form2").validate({

            rules: {
                price: {
                required: true,
                number: true
                },

                description: {
                required: true
                }
            }

        });
                $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Add Detail": function() {                       
                        var valid = $("#form2").validate().form();                       
                            if (valid) {
                                $("#save").button("enable");
                                addDetail();
                                $("#save").attr('disabled',false);                     
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },

                close: function() {

                    $("#price").val("");
                    $("#description").val("");
                }
            });

            $("#newDetail")
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        });

            $("#<%=form1.ClientID %>").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=txtDate.ClientID %> : {
                        required: true,
                        dateEU: true
                    },
                    <%=txtCompany.ClientID %> : {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {

                    form.submit();
                }

            });
        });


        function addDetail() {
            table.push({
            codigo: 0,
            documentoCompra: {
            "codigo": "0"
            },

            price: document.getElementById('price').value,
            description: document.getElementById('description').value
            });

            showRow(table.length - 1);
        }

        function removeDetail(r) {
            var node = r.parentNode;
                while (node && node.tagName !== 'TR') {
                    node = node.parentNode;
                }

            var i = node.rowIndex;

            document.getElementById('DetailTable').deleteRow(i);
            table.splice(i - 1, 1);

                if (table.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById('save').disabled=true;
                    $("#save").button("disable");
                }
        }

        function showRow(i) {
            if (table.length > 0) {
                var tbl = document.getElementById('DetailTable');

                var newRow = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);               

                var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(0);               
                cell3.innerHTML = table[i].description;

                var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(1);              
                cell4.innerHTML = table[i].price;                

                var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);               
                cell2.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><img src="images/delete.jpg" width="14" height="14" alt="Delete" onclick="removeDetail(this)"/></a>'

                document.getElementById('save').disabled=false;

            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Html and Asp.net markup:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <fieldset style="width: 85%">
        <legend>MASTER</legend>
        <div id="contenido1" class="ui-widget">
            <table width="90%" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="ui-widget-header ">
                        COMPANY
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="ui-widget-header ">
                        DATE
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="ui-widget-header ">
                        TYPE
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTipoDoc" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="BOLETA" Value="B" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="RECIBO CAJA CHICA" Value="R"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="FACTURA" Value="F"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>       
        <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save" disabled="disabled" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="cancelar" value="Cancel" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!--Detail -->
    <div>
        <fieldset style="width: 85%">
            <legend>DETAIL</legend>
            <div id="dialog-form" title="Add New Detail">
                <p>
                    All the fields are required.</p>
                <form id="form2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="description" id="lbldescription">
                                Description</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="price" id="lblprice">
                                Price</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>                   
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="ui-widget">
                <table id="DetailTable" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="text-align: center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                            <td width="60%">
                                Description
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                Price
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                Delete
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table border="0" style="width: 90%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <button id="newDetail" style="float: right">
                            Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Although it is true that I almost got it ready, I still have some doubts:

1. What do I have to do to remove the error messages from the controls inside the dialog, after I have closed the dialog without meeting the validation rules?
2. How do I do to always show the error messages just below the controls they validate?
3. Would you be kind enough to check whether it is correct what I've done with the validation of the dialog? I've first added the validation rules and inside the code that is executed when I press the  "Add Detail"  button, I've added a conditional to check whether the controls have been correctly validated , in which case, I close the dialog and add a new row to the Details" table

I've uploaded a [sample project(JqueryDialog_JqueryValidate)](https://skydrive.live.com/embedicon.aspx/Ejemplos/JqueryDialog%5E_JqueryValidate.rar?cid=37eb2546278f13bd&sc=documents)  to my skydrive , a very simple one indeed

Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated

***Edit*** :
CSS style needed to place the error label below the inputs

```
<style type="text/css">       
        input:focus
        {
            border: 2px dotted black;
        }
        input.error
        {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        label.error
        {
            color: white;
            text-indent:2px;           
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family: Nyala;
            background-color: red;
            display:block ;

        }
    </style>
```

Comment: can you implement sample project on http://jsfiddle.net/ to not make us deploy your project ourselves ?

Comment: but it has asp.net markup, is there any problem??

Comment: at least post some pieces of code here so we get the picture

Comment: @Didier - Sorry :( , I've added all the code I use. Please, take a look now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here for your three questions:

**1. What do I have to do to remove the error messages from the controls inside the dialog, after I have closed the dialog without meeting the validation rules?**

The plugin provides a resetForm() method on the validator object to reset the validation ([see doc](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm)).

When you call `validate()`, it actually returns a validator object that you can save and use afterwards:

```
var dialogFormValidator = $("#form2").validate({...});
```

In you 'close' button handler, you can then do:

```
close: function() {
    $("#price").val("");
    $("#description").val("");
    dialogFormValidator.resetForm();
}
```

*Edit*

Bind to the event `beforeClose` resets the form correctly (classes are not removed when binding to the `close` event:

```
beforeClose: function() {
    $("#price").val("");
    $("#description").val("");
    dialogFormValidator.resetForm();
}
```

**2. How do I do to always show the error messages just below the controls they validate?**

Use the `errorPlacement()` callback in the `validate()` options to place the error label wherever you want ([see doc](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)).

By default the  are added next to the input field. With some CSS you might able to show them 'below' the input though (with something like `display:block;` for inst.)

**3. dialog button handlers**

As for the reset you can use the validator object to check the validity:

```
var valid = dialogFormValidator.form();                       
if (valid) {
     $("#save").button("enable");
     addDetail();
     // why don't you use $("#save").button("disable") ??
     $("#save").attr('disabled',false);  // better use prop() for 'disabled' properties and not attr()              
     $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

Am not sure about the 'Add Detail' button handler. Why do you enable/disable the #Save element (in two different ways) ?

Comment: lol Don't ask me why , I don't even know myself why I ended up doing that XD ... it must be something due to spending way too many hours of late-night programming XD ...and you were right about everything you told me to do. Thank you soooooooo much! it works exactly as I wanted it!

Comment: sorry to bother you :S , but I got question about the resetForm() method, I did what you suggested and called this method from the 'close' button handler, and it works fine ..except for the fact that the 'error' class is not removed. The estrange thing is that if I call the method from within the 'cancel' button it does remove all the classes indicating invalid elements including the 'error' class

Comment: I know I can use `removeClass("error")` but I'd like to know if there's a different way of getting the same result without having to call `removeClass` for every single control on my form

Comment: Well, you can do it in one operation: `$('.error').removeClass('error');`

Comment: lol OK :D , but is it the normal behavior of `resetForm()` ?? I ask because I can't understand why it works wonders for the 'cancel' button but not for the 'close' button :(

Comment: I made a quick test to see what you were talking about. Binding to the event `beforeClose` instead of `close` resets the form correctly. I did not go through so i don't know the reason exactly. Maybe the resetForm() method has problems when the div is already hidden. Besides, you don't need to reset the form in the Cancel button, only in the beforeClose.

Comment: Thanks man, I have no words to thank you for all the help you've giving me :D

Answer (score 2):

I struggled hard with this issue; after several hours I concluded that Jquery render the DIALOG html element outside the form element.  Since Jquery.Validation plugin works only within the FORM  element, it is necessary to return back the Dialog inside the Form scope.  This can be done by the following open event handling:

```
  $('#dialogDivId').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      minheight: options.minheight,
      minwidth: options.minwidth,
      modal:false,
      open: function (type, data) {
             $(this).appendTo($('form')); // reinsert the dialog to the form           }
});
```

It solved my problem!!!

Hope I helped and save you the time I spent.